# Using json API pull to store in file or database

Tags: json, list, streaming, justin.tv

I am trying to pull data from the justin.tv API and store the echo I get in the below code in to a database or a file to be included in the sidebar of website. I am not sure on how to do this. The example of what I am trying to achieve is the live streamers list on the sidebar of teamliquid.net. Which I have done but doing it the way I have done it slows the site way down because it does about 50 json requests every time the page loads. I just need to get this in to a cached file that updates every 60 seconds or so. Any ideas?

```
<?php
$json_file = file_get_contents("http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=colcatz");
$json_array = json_decode($json_file, true);

if ($json_array[0]['name'] == 'live_user_colcatz') echo '<a href="http://www.twitch.tv/colcatz">coL.CatZ</a> Live<br>';

$json_file = file_get_contents("http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel=coldrewbie");
$json_array = json_decode($json_file, true);

if ($json_array[0]['name'] == 'live_user_coldrewbie') echo '<a href="http://www.twitch.tv/coldrewbie">coL.drewbie</a> Live<br>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure how you would imagine this being cached, but the code below is an adaption of a block of code I've used in the past for some Twitter work. There are a few things that could probably be done better from a security perspective. Anyway, this gives you a generic way of grabbing the Feed, parsing through it, and then sending it to the database.

Warning: This assumes that there is a database connection already established within your own system.

(*** Make sure you scroll to the bottom of the code window ***)

```
/**
 * Class SM
 *
 * Define a generic wrapper class with some system
 * wide functionality. In this case we'll give it
 * the ability to fetch a social media feed from
 * another server for parsing and possibly caching.
 *
 */

class SM {

  private $api, $init, $url;

  public function fetch_page_contents ($url) {

    $init = curl_init();

    try {
      curl_setopt($init, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($init, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);      
      curl_setopt($init, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);      
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      error_log($e->getMessage());
    }

    $output = curl_exec($init);
    curl_close($init);

    return $output;
  }

}


/**
 * Class JustinTV
 *
 * Define a specific site wrapper for getting the
 * timeline for a specific user from the JustinTV
 * website. Optionally you can return the code as
 * a JSON string or as a decoded PHP array with the
 * $api_decode argument in the get_timeline function.
 *
 */
class JustinTV extends SM {

  private $timeline_document,
          $api_user,
          $api_format,
          $api_url;

  public function get_timeline ($api_user, $api_decode = 1, $api_format = 'json', $api_url = 'http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list') {

    $timeline_document = $api_url . '.' . $api_format . '?channel=' . $api_user;

    $SM_init = new SM();

    $decoded_json = json_decode($SM_init->fetch_page_contents($timeline_document));

    // Make sure that our JSON is really JSON
    if ($decoded_json === null && json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
      error_log('Badly formed, dangerous, or altered JSON string detected. Exiting program.');
    }

    if ($api_decode == 1) {
      return $decoded_json;
    }

    return $SM_init->fetch_page_contents($timeline_document);   
  }

}


/**
 * Instantiation of the class
 *
 * Instantiate our JustinTV class, fetch a user timeline
 * from JustinTV for the user colcatz. The loop through
 * the results and enter each of the individual results
 * into a database table called cache_sm_justintv.
 *
 */
$SM_JustinTV = new JustinTV();

$user_timeline = $SM_JustinTV->get_timeline('colcatz');

foreach ($user_timeline AS $entry) {

  // Here you could check whether the entry already exists in the system before you cache it, thus reducing duplicate ID's

  $date = date('U');

  $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO `cache_sm_justintv` (`id`, `cache_content`, `date`) VALUES (%d, '%s', )", $entry->id, $entry, $date);
  $result = mysql_query($query);

  // Do some other stuff and then close the MySQL Connection when your done

}
```

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea how to implement this or even what it does.

Comment: Sorry for adding confusion.If copy code either from above or from the Gist here https://gist.github.com/1478159 and then save it as a PHP file you can run the program. If you're needing help with the MySQL part of things as well, let me know.

Comment: So what exactly does this do? Does it store the echo that I have in my above post? Basically I want it say "col.Catz" in a list on the sidebar of my website if the json returns that he is "live" and nothing if he is not. There are about 50 streamers that i need to check and display. See the "live streams" area on the sidebar of http://www.teamliquid.net for an example of what I want to do but do it so that it does not slow down the website every time it loads.